# Password regex not working fine

Tags: regex

i'm using

```
function validatePassword(password)
{
    var re = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[$@.$!%*#?&0-9])[A-Za-z\d$@.$!%*#?&]{0,100}$/i;
    return re.test(password); 
}
```

for password contains at least one numbers or special character it's working fine with atleast one character if no character it always returns false even though i give number or special character

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean, and supply some examples? "If no character" - do you mean a letter? There is a `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` lookahead that requires a letter. If you do not need that, remove this lookahead.

Comment: if i give only one number or special character it should return true without any letter

Comment: you can remove `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` and `{0,100}$/i` and try , here {0,100} means minimum count 0, and maximum size of password is 100

Answer (score 2):

The `/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[$@.$!%*#?&0-9])[A-Za-z\d$@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}$/i` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` - requires at least one ASCII letter in the line
- `(?=.*[$@.$!%*#?&0-9])` - requires a digit or some special symbols.
- `[A-Za-z\d$@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}`  - 8 to 15 letters, digits and specified special symbols
- `$` - end of string
- `/i` - case insensitive matching

**The `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` lookahead requires a letter**. If you do not need that, remove this lookahead.

Use

```
/^(?=.*[$@.!%*#?&0-9])[A-Za-z\d@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}$/i
```

Or - if the *password must contain atleast one number and one special character*:

```
/^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^$@.!%*#?&]*[$@.!%*#?&])[a-z0-9@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}$/i
```

where `(?=.*[$@.!%*#?&0-9])` is split into 2 lookaheads: `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` that requires at least 1 digit and `(?=[^$@.!%*#?&]*[$@.!%*#?&])` that requires at least one special symbol from the specified set.

Demo:

```js
function validatePassword(password)
{
    var re = /^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^$@.!%*#?&]*[$@.!%*#?&])[a-z0-9@.$!%*#?&]{8,15}$/i;
    return re.test(password); 
}
console.log(validatePassword("password"));
console.log(validatePassword("12345678"));
console.log(validatePassword("12345678moreWords"));
console.log(validatePassword("12468word!"));
```

Comment: in third `console.log` , there is no special symbol, still it return true, but his requirement is password must contain atleast one number and one special character.

Comment: Aha, so create 2 lookaheads out of 1. I updated the answer with the demo.